# Visual Basic - Reset at 00:00

Tags: vb.net, date, reset

I've got an question about resetting a label every night at the same time.

What do i mean:
1. when starting the program my label.text = 750
every time someone clicks a button the label text reduces with 1 so
750
749
748 etc etc

but now i want that every day at 00:00 the label's text resets to 750.

is that possible??

Comment: Will your application run 24X7?

Comment: No but i thought maybe it was possible to make something that save some settings, and if the app loads it will check if 00:00 is already passed.

Comment: If your application is not running continuously, you must save some data in a `file` or `database`.

Comment: Oke, i don't have any experience with databases so could you maybe help me a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Javed Akram's comment is correct -- none of this is going to matter, if the program isn't running at midnight.

However, for what you actually asked for - resetting a count at midnight - consider adding a TIMER to your project. You really only need the timer to click once a day (at midnight):

```
Private Sub SetInterval()
    ' Calculate how many milliseconds until the timer ticks again:
    ' Start by calculating the number of seconds between now and tomorrow.
    ' Multiply by 1000, then add 50 more -- this is to make sure that the
    ' timer runs 1/50 of a second AFTER midnight, so that we can
    ' re-calculate the interval again at that time.
    Timer1.Interval = CInt( _
        DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, Now, Today.AddDays(1)) * 1000 + 50)
End Sub
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ' Reset the interval, so that we run again tomorrow at midnight.
    SetInterval()

    ' Now, reset your label
    Label1.Text = "750"    ' Or whatever else needs to happen to reset the count
End Sub
```

You'll also need to add a call to SetInterval in Form_Load (or whatever your program initialization is), to set up the very first interval.

---

On an almost completely *UN-*related note, does anyone know why the Date class has an AddMilliseconds function, but Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateInterval (and therefore the DateDiff function) doesn't have Milliseconds? It's non-symmetrical.